# Playwright - Bypassing Fido2 u2f

Tags: playwright, playwright-python, fido, fido-u2f

I'm using Playwright to automate things on a website that I am using Fido2 u2f. I can't run it in headless mode as I need to be ready to touch my u2f when it's prompted. This is very annoying.

Is there a way to accept the u2f without me having to click it? Via code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [virtual authenticators API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#sctn-automation-virtual-authenticators) defined in the WebAuthn spec to programmatically set up automatic responses to WebAuthn in your automated testing pipeline .

The endpoints defined in there are REST requests you make **in the browser**, so as long as PlayWright gives you a mechanism for executing JS in the headless browser you're testing with then you should be able to set up a software authenticator to respond to WebAuthn API invocations without any interaction on your part.